# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'place_of_birthday' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I got an error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'place_of_birthday' doesn't have a default value SQL: 
>       insert into `users` (`full_name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Evan Agustian Lukius, evan.agustian.148@gmail.com, $2y$10$uAK3YAhu8YxAvuRRuo.Ml.wQ2rYXXT7FylcNwLFjOk1lYPS3AICoa

**Here is my error message screenshot:**

[image: photo]

**How to solve this error?**

Comment: you are not passing value for place_of_birthday filed and in database it has not default value means null or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your migration you can do this to make the column nullable:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('place_of_birthday')->nullable();
    });
}
```

`->nullable()` Designate that the column allows NULL values

Comment: Still error @dff

Answer (score 1):

if you are not passing any value in your non-nullable column it will give you this error everytime so make the column nullable. Change in your migration file:

like this:

```
$table->string('place_of_birthday')->nullable(); //assuming you have string column. no matter what type of column u have just use ->nullable()
```